# How to use spreadoperator to clone and set a value of a nested object

Tags: javascript

How can I set a nested object value when cloning an object?
The solution below does not work.

```
const a={1:{isOpen: true, hasChildren: false}}
const aClone ={...a, [1][isOpen]:false}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I understand properly, but you can simply set it as you would declaring a normal object:

```js
const a = { 1: { isOpen: true, hasChildren: false } };
const aClone = { ...a, 1: { ...a[1], isOpen: false } };

console.log(a);
console.log(aClone);
```

Comment: Not given in this question, But this would overwrite the complete object not retaining the (possible) other fields?

Comment: Yes, that is my problem too, it will overwrite other props. I updated the question.

Comment: Other properties in `1`